# Download file from server with generic handler

Tags: c#

I am trying to download a pdf a generated, my code is as follow:

```
public class GetPDF : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        PDFGenerator generatePDF = new PDFGenerator();
        FileInfo file = generatePDF.GeneratePDFHtml();

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }


    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried quite a few resources from the web. 
I does not break, it does not error, it just does nothing. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How do you want to generate pdf file. In any event like button click

Comment: By taking the HTML of the page, covnerting it into a pdf and saving it. The pdf file works perfectly, I just need to download it, but I have absolutely no luck with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear your question but if are successful to generate the file then you want to push to the client. I believe you are using update panel inside your aspx page and you have to add a trigger to your control to make a postback.

```
<Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnPrint" />
</Triggers>
```

Add this equivalent trigger to your page

Comment: Thx, the answer is the postback, i am using knockout and have no postbacks on the page. Thank you

Comment: Happy to hear you are successful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the parameter `context` instead of the static property `HttpContext.Current` here.

Comment: I have also tried doing that, I end up with the same result. nothing... Thank you